# crash on launching a class

Tags: android, class

My app crashes when I try to launch it:

```
DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
```

Here, Is the code of the class:

```
 private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try{
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
   }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
 }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `my app crashes` share crash log with question

Comment: Not is possible to help you only this code.

Comment: maybe internet permission! maybe thousand other things no one can help without the logs

Comment: I found my problem is here:  " Task<Location> locationResult = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();"   because the error on debug is  "No such instance field: 'mFusedLocationProviderClient'"

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass some value to **DownloadTask** AsyncTask. Also your way of calling AsyncTask is wrong. Should be like

```
DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
downloadTask.execute("SOME VALUE");
```

Since **doInBackground** function is expecting some of the String and you considered **url[0]** which is getting null. So your application getting crashed.